# Create multiple blog in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

Recently I am trying to learn about Wordpress. I have succeed to create a blog by using Wordpress and Xampp. Now, I want to create another blog, but I cant find any option to add a new blog at Wordpress wp-admin.php. It seems that Wordpress is only limited to one blog. Is there any way to create a multiple blog?

Cheers,
Alvinadi

Answer (score 1):

See the following article to [Set Multiple Blog sites](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-using-multisite). To begin with, modify the WordPress configuration file `wp-config.php`, activating the multisite networking.

Add the following line above `/* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or just use categorys and then just create archive pages..